# Can vs that ( /kæn/ vs /ðæt/ )

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, received-pronunciation, ae-raising, weak-forms

I’ve finally decided to take a look at my English pronunciation and it is being an awesome new world. I am focused on Received Pronunciation (British Standard) and one question comes to mind for which I can find no answer on the internet.

The *a* spelling on *C**A**N* and *TH**A**T* should have the same pronunciation according to the pronunciation symbol ‘æ’, but they don’t.

The pronunciation of *that* as /ðæt/ seems quite right, but  shouldn’t *can* be /ken/ not /kæn/?

Comment: I don't recognize the phonemic (phonetic? eye-dialect?) transcription **/ken/** here. If you just mean that sometimes the vowel in ***can*** is reduced to a schwa, I don't see the relevance. The vowel in ***that*** can also be reduced in exactly the same way.

Comment: There is no single way to pronounce these words when considering dialectal variation.  http://forvo.com/search/can/en/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. As I am a beginner I really do not understand. Formally they have the same 'æ' symbol and I've searched on different dictionaries + forvo and in UK they are pronounced differently (that vs can). CAN is always pronounced as /ken/ and formally should be pronounced as /kæn/. I am talking in purely formal ways. If then in practice we have the freedom to do it otherwise is another issue.

Comment: @viery365: If by that you mean UK speakers always reduce the vowel in *can* to a schwa (and by implication, that US speakers *don't*), you're simply mistaken.

Comment: I think this may be an RP system that distinguishes tense vowels with colons. In these /e/ is IPA /ɛ/ as in _ken, men, ten_. And in the US, _can_ is mostly pronounced /kɛn/. The pronunciation /kæn/ is most likely to be short for  /kænʔ/_can't_, which always uses /æ/.

Comment: 'can't' is /kɑːnt/ . The symbol /æ/ is more like 'hat' or 'back'. It is a short sound while /a:/ is long sound.

Comment: I know that I pronounce ***can*** in at least 3 different ways in different situations.  While I am an American, I have to believe that this would be true for BE as well - so that likely means at least 6 different pronunciations right there.

Comment: This question seems related, though as I mention in my answer there I haven't heard of /æ/ being tensed before nasals in British English, only in North American English: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258757/pronunciation-of-words-like-thanks-land-and/258786#258786

Comment: @FumbleFingers The determiner and pronoun *that* has no weak form. It's only the subordinator *that* which does.

Comment: I don't really understand your question very well, and I think there's a way you can clarify it. Do you think *can* rhymes with *man*? Do you think  with *can* rhymes with *pen*? Do you think *can, man,* and *pen* all rhyme? In AmE, *can* often rhymes with *pen* and not *man*, but I don't know whether this ever happens in BrE.

Comment: Yes. According to the dictionaries the American pronunciation for 'can' is /kən/ and that makes sense. However, the problem concernes the British Standard. But the link you have posted is useful because it explains that /æ/ can be pronounced in different ways. Thank you!

Comment: @Peter Shor The question is that as a foreigner I do not know if in British Standard _can_ rhymes with _Pen_ and I wanted to know.  According to the official phonetics _can_ should have the same _æ_ as the word _that_ which it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I think it's very likely that the vowels in *can* and *that* are somewhat different for many standard BrE speakers, because in English vowels often get changed slightly by the following vowels (so for me, *moth* and *law* have quite different vowels, but they represent the same phoneme and they're both between the neighboring vowels *coat* and *cot*). If that's the reason for what you're hearing, the vowel of *can* should be the same as that of *man* and not of *pen*.

Comment: @Peter: Being just an "ordinary" native speaker, I would find it almost impossible to actually hear whether any given instance of *I **can send** it over* actually involves repeating the same vowel sound, whether in a BrE or AmE accent. I think possibly this question is a matter of [the difference between “phonetic” and “phonemic”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104224/what-is-the-difference-between-phonetic-and-phonemic)

Comment: @Peter Shor Ok, thank you:) Now I understand:) Thank you for your explanation:) Indeed, by the Cambridge Dictionary _can_ is /kæn/ and _man_ is /mæn/. So, can=man is explained. _that_ however is /ðæt/ and is very different of the _a_ of can or the _a_ of man

Comment: They might just sound very different to you because the vowels of your native language don't match the vowels of English; they sound the same to us.

Comment: Yes, you are right:) My language is Portuguese and we have many sounds for the vowels _a_ and _e_. But I tell you: I am finding English pronunciation extremely difficult!!!

Comment: @Jim - I'm not sure I agree with you a hundred percent on your logic, there, Jim. Are you sure RP really uses completely different sounds for the same vowel as Americans?

Comment: @medica- I think my point is that Americans don't always use the same sounds in a given dialect not to mention the differences in New Yorkers, Upstate New Yorkers, Georgians, and Texans

Answer (score 5):

1. kæn
2. kən
3. ðæt
4. ðət

The strong forms of the words *can* and *that* both have the TRAP vowel in RP. This is the same vowel as in the word *cat* /kæt/. These forms of the words are shown in examples (1) and (3) repsectively. The auxiliary verb *can* is usually only strong when stressed or when stranded (ie when not followed by another verb).

The subordinator *that* and the auxiliary verb *can* both have weak forms which we use when they are not stressed. These are usually said with a schwa vowel, /ə/ as shown in examples (2) and (4). However, *can* may also be realised with a syllabic consonant, as in /kn̩/.

The determiner *that* as in *that elephant*, and the pronoun *that* as in *give me that* have no weak forms. Neither does the noun *can*, of course.

Speakers who are just starting out on their journey into English pronunciation may well mistake a schwa for another vowel. It can be difficult to recognise for the uninitiated, having no association with any particular orthographic vowel.

[Speakers with razor sharp ears may be able to detect a slight difference in the quality of the vowels in *can* and *that*. The vowel in *can* will be nasalised because of the following alveolar nasal sound, /n/.]

Comment: That's the answer and I am glad you understood the question:) Thank you very much!